# Connecting Nexus 7.2 (2013) to Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, nexus

I can't get to connect my Nexus 7.2 (2nd gen or 2013 or FHD) to Eclispe. I followed all the topics available (even those about Nexus 7.1 first gen.) but the drivers provided by Google or Nexus seem to not work... Impossible to see my new Nexus 7.1 in Eclipse...
I was wondering if I was the only one to experience this problem ? or if someone has found a solution to that problem.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem but it was solved after I installed the correct drivers through Device Manager (My Nexus 7 showed a warning icon in Device Manager prior). I downloaded the drivers manually.

Also make sure you have the USB Driver here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html

And just in case you weren't aware, you need to have Developer Mode enabled on your Nexus 7.

Comment: Thanks Jazcash, just to check, do you have the last Nexus 7 or the first nexus 7 generation ? It's important to difference both versions. (I'm aware of the Developer Mode thanks).

Comment: Well, I did what you said on my home computer but it doesn't work so I tried on my work computer and it worked... The only difference is the Windows 7 version (Home at home, Enterprise at work). Don't know why it doesn't work at home. Thanks !

Comment: I have the newest version. Does your Nexus 7 show as faulty in Device Manager at home?

Comment: I deleted all Eclipse files, workspace and uninstall nexus 7 driver in Device manager and did exactly what I did on my work computer but same problem... In device manager, Nexus 7 appears with a yellow warning. I updated the driver (like I did on my work PC) but it tells me that "Windows couldn't find any driver for my device" ! Crazy ! Only difference between both situations, the windows version and the computer brand...

Comment: Tried this guide? http://www.theandroidsoul.com/nexus-7-2013-drivers-installation-guide/

Comment: Yes I did but I have the same issue than people in the comments section of the article...

Comment: Sorry, no idea what the problem is then. I'd suggest just Googling around and trying different drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answer for me is probably that it doesn't work with Windows 7 Familiale (Home) Premium but it works with Windows 7 Enterprise.

Comment: OK ! I don't know  why but I just pluged in my Nexus 7 to may computer and it works ! I did'nt change anything to my computer or Nexus since last time... I really don't understand what hapened...